# Image Resizing, Java

Tags: java, image, resize

Could someone explain why this line of code isn't working. No errors are given. It simply doesn't resize the image.

```
image = ImageIO.read(file);

image.getScaledInstance(ImageDisplayBox.getWidth(), ImageDisplayBox.getHeight());
ImageDisplayBox.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

I've looked at the other answers on Stackoverflow and noticed a lot of people using the .getScaledInstance method.

I (think) it might be the fact that I have it as .setIcon - Although I'm not the best with Java.

The image is printed but displays only the top left of the image due to size.

Comment: `image.getScaledInstance(ImageDisplayBox.getWidth(), ImageDisplayBox.getHeight(), 5);`  Re `5` - don't use magic numbers.  That is what the defined constants are for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're ignoring the returned value. You want:

```
image = image.getScaledInstance(ImageDisplayBox.getWidth(),
                                ImageDisplayBox.getHeight(), 5);
```

Or maybe to make things clearer:

```
Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(ImageDisplayBox.getWidth(),
                                       ImageDisplayBox.getHeight(), 5);
ImageDisplayBox.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaled));
```

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> Creates a scaled version of this image. A new Image object is returned which will render the image at the specified width and height by default. The new Image object may be loaded asynchronously even if the original source image has already been loaded completely.

Note that that doesn't say anything about changing the *existing* image. It just creates a *new* image with the given size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

This should work

```
Image scaled =image.getScaledInstance(ImageDisplayBox.getWidth(),
                                      ImageDisplayBox.getHeight(), 5);
ImageDisplayBox.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaled));
```